# Delete dynamically generated CheckBoxes in C#

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am generating dynamically Checkbox-buttons on a panel according to my SQL data. I created a button to "refresh" my buttons, I mean I delete / update buttons. My problem is I cannot delete the old buttons. After a created the buttons I am  trying to delete a specific one:

```
foreach (CheckBox item in panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    panel.Controls.Remove(item);
}
```

There are only a few deleted. Any suggestion?

Comment: this code seems ok to me: I suspect you are not adding the "missing" checkboxes to panel.Controls, consider dumb each check box Text (or Tag, if you set every checbox with a different tag when creating int) returned by `panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()`

Comment: You are modifying a collection you are iterating over... Make a copy of the list of controls that you iterate over and remove them from the original.

Comment: @fredrik, I don't think so: he is iterating on the IEnumerable returned by LINQ `Oftype<>`  and removing fro `panel.Controls`, they are not the same collectio. Actually, your comment was the first thing I though after reading the question, but if I'm not missing something, that's wrong

Comment: @GianPaolo Seeing that the accepted answer is just what I suggested, I'd say you're wrong. It might be the IEnumerable returned by LINQ - but there is no guarantee that it's a IEnumerable that works on a copy of the list...

Comment: @fredrik you're right, I've just checked [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4ba4a3f8a5530e33). `OfType` returns a different object but it keeps iterating on the original collection while returning each matching element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the list of the controls to delete before deleting them. You’re trying to delete items from the collection you’re iterating over, which can be problematic.

Comment: I tryied something like this ´´´   foreach (CheckBox item in panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
            {
                List<Control> collect = new List<Control>();
                collect.Add(item);

                foreach (Control c in collect)
                {
                    panel.Controls.Remove(c);                }

            } ´´´   and it has the same result.

Comment: A simple way to do it is something like `foreach (CheckBox item in panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToArray()) { panel.Controls.Remove(item); }`  The `ToArray()` call will essentially make a copy of the list before you start iterating.